# Oracle date / order by question

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to select a date from oracle table  formatted like select `(to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY'))` but I also want to order the result set on this date format.

I want them to be ordered like dates not strings.

Like this

```
09/2009
10/2009
11/2009
12/2009
01/2010
02/2010
03/2010
04/2010
05/2010
06/2010
07/2010
08/2010
09/2010
10/2010
11/2010
12/2010
```

Not like

```
01/2010
02/2010
03/2010
04/2010
05/2010
06/2010
07/2010
08/2010
09/2009
09/2010
10/2009
10/2010
11/2009
11/2010
12/2009
12/2010
```

Any way to do this in sql?

Full SQL is:

```
SELECT (to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')) as monthYear, count(req_id) as count
FROM   REQUISITION_CURRENT t
GROUP BY to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select monthyear,yr,month,count(req_id)
from
(
SELECT (to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')) as monthYear, to_char(req_date,'YYYY') yr, to_char(req_date,'mm') month, req_id
FROM   REQUISITION_CURRENT t
) x
GROUP BY monthyear,yr,month
order by yr, month
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It works and it's efficient, but looks a little messy.

```
select to_char(trunc(req_date, 'MM'),'MM/YYYY') as monthYear
      ,count(req_id) as count
  from requisition_current
 group 
    by trunc(req_date, 'MM')
 order
    by trunc(req_date, 'MM');
```

Comment: This works much better, and doesn't have as much overhead as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
Select req_date, (to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')) from MY_TABLE order by req_date
```

You are free to add additional sort fields, even if they are the same field.

Comment: @Saeed, thought user561793 would like to see them together, for understanding the question. You are right, though, req_date is not necessary on the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `order by req_date` instead of `order by to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')`.

Comment: Sorry. I am also doing a group by full sql is -select (to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')) as monthYear from REQUISITION_CURRENT t group by to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY') order by monthYear So I cant order by req_date.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT ... 
ORDER BY MIN(req_date)
```

That'll get around Oracle's rules about what can be selected after a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I am considerably late to the party, but the most intuitive way I've found to achieve this is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY') as monthYear, 
   count(req_id) as count
FROM   
   REQUISITION_CURRENT t
GROUP BY 
   to_char(req_date,'MM/YYYY')
ORDER BY 
   to_date(monthYear,'MM/YYYY')
```

It's may not the most computationally efficient method since it converts the date to a character and then back to a date, but that is precisely what you are asking a query like this to do. It also saves you from adding support columns or nesting subqueries.